# I have problem for calculate IDI and NRI with R

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the integrated discrimination improvement for two Cox regression models (time, event), using the survIDINRI package and the IDI.INF function and I have an error

This is the code for the function:

```
D=subset(donnees,select=c("time","status","age","smoking","hospit_HF","symptomatic_angina","cardiac2","nb_seg_LGE","ischemie"))
D$status=as.numeric(D$status==1 | D$status==2)
D=D[!is.na(apply(D,1,mean)),] ; dim(D)
mydata=D

indata2=mydata;
indata1=mydata[,-8];
indata0=mydata[,c(-7,-8)];n=nrow(D);
covs2<-as.matrix(indata2[,c(-1,-2)]);
covs1<-as.matrix(indata1[,c(-1,-2)]);
covs0<-as.matrix(indata0[,c(-1,-2)]);
t0=2
x<- IDI.INF(mydata[,1:2], covs0, covs1, t0) ;
```

And I get the following error message:

Error in unoecdf(cc, pdiff[case], Wi[case] * PTB.Vi[case]) :
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)

If someone have a solution it's would be great

Thanks in advance

Marilyn

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. I share the 700 first lines because with all lines there is too much characters.

Comment: Hi. I used your `mydata` but I cannot reproduce the error message of your post. `IDI.INF` works with no errors.

Comment: Hi, How it's possible ? A different version of R ? I have version 4.0.2 or another reason ?

Comment: I have tested my code in the same environment with the dataset of 700 rows and I have the same error. It's strange

Comment: Always the same error ... I don't know what it's happen

Comment: Hi,I have remove survIDINRI, restart R and reinstall it, but I have always the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
> dput(round(mydata[1:700,],1))
structure(list(time = c(6.8, 6.8, 6.9, 7.8, 5.6, 6.7, 8.3, 6.6, 
7.8, 3.7, 6.9, 6.5, 7, 3.4, 7.4, 6.8, 6.8, 6.9, 7.8, 0.2, 7, 
5.2, 6.9, 6.4, 6.5, 6.9, 6.7, 6.9, 6.9, 3.5, 0.7, 1.9, 7.3, 6.9, 
7.4, 6.9, 2, 3.1, 6.8, 8, 8.1, 6.8, 6.9, 6.9, 6.8, 0.2, 7.9, 
6.9, 5.2, 8.1, 6.7, 6.8, 7.8, 8.1, 7, 6.7, 1.2, 7.8, 7.8, 6.7, 
6.6, 6.9, 6.9, 6.4, 7.2, 2.1, 5.2, 7.5, 7.8, 1.1, 0.8, 1.9, 6.9, 
6.9, 7.1, 6.5, 7.7, 6.9, 7.4, 6.9, 7.1, 3.6, 7.9, 6.7, 6.9, 0.4, 
6.9, 5.9, 6.7, 6.8, 7.9, 6.5, 8, 5.1, 6.9, 6.9, 8.2, 7, 5.2, 
7, 4.3, 8.3, 6.8, 6.7, 6.8, 6.8, 7.2, 1.5, 7.1, 5.5, 6.7, 6.8, 
6.7, 6.7, 6.5, 6.8, 6.9, 6.5, 6.8, 7.8, 7.6, 6.7, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 
6.8, 2.3, 8, 6.9, 5.2, 6.8, 6.8, 6.8, 1.8, 6.4, 6.7, 6.8, 6.8, 
6.7, 7.8, 6.9, 8.1, 6.6, 8, 6.9, 6.4, 6.8, 7.9, 6.4, 6.8, 6.5, 
1.1, 6.8, 6.5, 6.7, 6.7, 6.6, 8.1, 7.4, 6.9, 1.8, 6.9, 6.9, 6.8, 
6.7, 6.1, 6.9, 7.8, 1.8, 7.8, 6.7, 5.4, 6.9, 6.7, 1.5, 7, 7, 
6.9, 6.7, 6.9, 7, 6.8, 2.3, 6.8, 6.9, 6.8, 7.8, 8.2, 1.2, 7.1, 
6.8, 6.7, 6.5, 6.9, 6.9, 4.1, 6.6, 6.8, 1.8, 4.3, 7.8, 6.8, 7.1, 
8.3, 6.8, 3.7, 6.4, 6.9, 7.1, 6.9, 7.1, 7.8, 7.4, 6.9, 6.7, 6.7, 
7.2, 6.9, 6.9, 6.4, 8, 7.5, 6.9, 5.2, 6.9, 7.4, 7.8, 6.7, 6.8, 
6.9, 6.4, 8.1, 8.3, 6.5, 6.7, 8.1, 8.1, 7.9, 6.8, 7, 7, 5.4, 
7.8, 6.8, 5.5, 6.8, 6.9, 7.8, 8, 6.4, 6.9, 7.9, 6.9, 6.7, 7.9, 
6.5, 7.8, 6.5, 6.7, 6.8, 8.1, 7.1, 8.1, 7, 6.9, 6.6, 6.8, 6.8, 
6.6, 6.4, 6.7, 7.1, 8.2, 7.8, 6.8, 6.9, 8.3, 8.2, 6.7, 6.9, 6.6, 
7.8, 6.7, 6.8, 7.8, 7.8, 6.9, 6.9, 7.1, 8.1, 6.8, 6.8, 7, 7.6, 
6.7, 6.4, 6.7, 7, 7.2, 6.7, 7.2, 6.8, 6.9, 7.8, 6.7, 7, 7.8, 
6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 8.1, 7.1, 6.8, 7.8, 8.1, 7.8, 8.1, 6.6, 1.8, 6.9, 
6.9, 7.8, 6.9, 2.5, 7.4, 6.6, 6.4, 6.9, 7.1, 7.6, 7, 6.9, 6.7, 
8.1, 6.9, 4.8, 1.9, 6.5, 0.1, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 2.8, 6.7, 7.8, 6.9, 
6.9, 6.8, 6.8, 6.9, 8.1, 4.9, 8.2, 6.8, 6.4, 5.6, 6.9, 6.9, 7.8, 
6.7, 8.1, 6.8, 7.8, 6.8, 6.8, 8.1, 6.8, 6.8, 6.8, 1.2, 2, 7, 
1.1, 5.6, 8.3, 6.7, 7, 6.5, 3.5, 7.8, 8.1, 7.1, 3.8, 6.8, 8.1, 
7.7, 4.2, 7, 6.9, 6.9, 6.7, 7.6, 6.9, 6.4, 1.6, 6.4, 6.7, 8.2, 
6.8, 7.8, 6.4, 2.7, 8.1, 7.7, 6.5, 0.5, 6.9, 2.3, 5.6, 6.4, 6.4, 
6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 8.2, 6.7, 5.7, 6.6, 5.3, 3.2, 7.4, 7, 6.5, 6.7, 
6.7, 8.2, 6.7, 6.7, 6.8, 7.8, 6.9, 6.9, 7, 6.6, 8.2, 6.9, 7.8, 
6.8, 6.9, 7.8, 8.3, 5.2, 6.9, 8, 6.7, 6.5, 2.4, 7.2, 6.5, 8, 
8.3, 7, 6.4, 6.8, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 7.8, 8.1, 6.6, 7.8, 6.7, 6.9, 
1.2, 6.7, 7, 8.3, 4.4, 6.9, 6.9, 7.8, 8.2, 7.2, 6.8, 7, 6.8, 
1.4, 6.9, 6.7, 8, 6.9, 7.1, 7.8, 6.5, 6.4, 0.9, 6.9, 6.9, 8.2, 
6.7, 6.9, 6.8, 6.9, 8, 6.5, 6.8, 7.7, 4.3, 6.8, 6.8, 6.8, 6.9, 
6.9, 7.9, 6.8, 6.3, 7, 7, 2.2, 5.2, 8.2, 8, 6.8, 2.3, 7.8, 6.8, 
6.6, 7.8, 6.8, 6.8, 6.9, 6.8, 6.8, 8, 6.9, 7.1, 1.3, 6.8, 6.9, 
7.4, 6.9, 6.8, 6.8, 6.9, 7.6, 8.2, 8, 7.8, 6.9, 8.1, 7.4, 1.6, 
6.8, 6.8, 7, 6.4, 7.1, 6.8, 6.9, 6.4, 6.6, 6.8, 6.5, 6.5, 1.7, 
8.1, 5.8, 7.8, 3.1, 6.9, 8.3, 0.2, 6.9, 2.6, 6.9, 6.9, 7.8, 5.7, 
7, 7.8, 6.8, 6.9, 6.7, 7.4, 6.8, 8.1, 6.5, 6.8, 6.6, 6.8, 8, 
6.3, 6.7, 7, 8, 6.9, 6.7, 6.8, 6.8, 7, 3.4, 6.5, 6.5, 7.1, 6.5, 
6.8, 6.8, 7.2, 6.8, 8.3, 7.8, 6.9, 6.9, 7.5, 6.7, 6.7, 6.9, 6.7, 
7.1, 7.8, 6.9, 6.9, 6.8, 6.7, 7, 6.9, 6.9, 7.8, 6.9, 6.8, 6.9, 
6.9, 6.4, 6.6, 5.2, 7.8, 6.7, 6.7, 7, 7.8, 5.1, 7.6, 7, 6.8, 
6.9, 6.8, 6.9, 7.1, 8.1, 4.2, 6.5, 7.8, 7.1, 7.3, 7.2, 6.8, 6.8, 
6.9, 8.3, 6.4, 6.9, 0.8, 6.5, 6.8, 6.8, 6.7, 8.3, 0.5, 6.5, 6.8, 
7, 6.7, 6.7, 7.8, 6.9, 7.1, 1.4, 6.8, 5.3, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 
7.1, 6.9, 6.8, 6.9, 6.7, 6.8, 6.7, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 8.1, 8.1, 6.8, 
7, 7, 7.1, 6.6, 6.9, 6.7, 2, 7.8, 6.8, 7.9, 7.8, 4.4, 7.2, 6.6
), status = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), age = c(81, 63, 87, 65, 
65, 81, 61, 65, 68, 81, 59, 67, 68, 83, 56, 65, 64, 82, 76, 61, 
83, 78, 65, 73, 46, 67, 76, 83, 79, 73, 59, 73, 75, 77, 56, 78, 
72, 81, 78, 50, 85, 76, 64, 79, 67, 55, 72, 84, 71, 82, 68, 75, 
72, 74, 73, 83, 85, 69, 64, 72, 82, 73, 79, 57, 78, 63, 72, 84, 
76, 74, 77, 85, 77, 59, 71, 74, 80, 84, 70, 74, 77, 82, 58, 79, 
77, 83, 69, 81, 75, 65, 65, 54, 80, 73, 64, 69, 78, 62, 77, 47, 
65, 58, 79, 83, 72, 69, 77, 79, 79, 75, 71, 82, 70, 83, 82, 86, 
77, 51, 85, 61, 77, 63, 78, 64, 59, 71, 79, 86, 75, 77, 78, 69, 
75, 67, 68, 72, 68, 52, 81, 70, 82, 68, 80, 86, 72, 70, 78, 68, 
65, 69, 67, 88, 77, 67, 83, 76, 85, 79, 59, 58, 79, 79, 74, 80, 
79, 71, 75, 78, 72, 61, 89, 64, 79, 54, 59, 56, 67, 59, 70, 71, 
69, 64, 63, 62, 83, 80, 72, 78, 91, 78, 46, 84, 72, 68, 80, 80, 
88, 77, 63, 68, 85, 56, 57, 71, 84, 84, 79, 76, 74, 74, 74, 60, 
73, 79, 76, 86, 82, 79, 58, 58, 78, 73, 73, 73, 82, 70, 60, 54, 
64, 77, 66, 64, 59, 74, 62, 78, 76, 85, 63, 78, 73, 81, 79, 91, 
89, 56, 56, 71, 87, 88, 65, 65, 67, 69, 67, 60, 72, 81, 64, 73, 
77, 65, 74, 52, 74, 72, 72, 83, 61, 51, 86, 69, 69, 69, 84, 75, 
83, 77, 70, 78, 65, 79, 85, 70, 73, 63, 80, 74, 82, 43, 88, 74, 
73, 77, 60, 72, 66, 73, 70, 86, 66, 79, 65, 48, 68, 56, 72, 72, 
81, 82, 85, 76, 81, 64, 66, 64, 62, 44, 68, 80, 87, 59, 81, 85, 
61, 83, 58, 71, 81, 86, 83, 55, 59, 66, 72, 82, 75, 64, 68, 42, 
61, 76, 76, 63, 77, 76, 78, 70, 71, 79, 78, 61, 80, 64, 80, 80, 
69, 65, 78, 79, 68, 85, 78, 87, 74, 80, 79, 81, 80, 81, 65, 72, 
78, 82, 66, 75, 86, 41, 41, 58, 77, 59, 71, 51, 70, 48, 46, 63, 
76, 88, 76, 76, 61, 44, 71, 79, 63, 67, 71, 77, 69, 84, 85, 79, 
79, 70, 82, 73, 79, 51, 72, 72, 75, 72, 70, 76, 82, 73, 80, 80, 
70, 68, 71, 57, 78, 82, 74, 80, 62, 80, 70, 55, 70, 76, 84, 76, 
63, 60, 78, 72, 78, 76, 80, 62, 65, 68, 85, 71, 75, 78, 69, 63, 
69, 60, 82, 80, 69, 64, 76, 52, 76, 58, 54, 79, 65, 76, 75, 74, 
65, 81, 89, 52, 81, 89, 67, 72, 62, 53, 51, 67, 77, 52, 64, 62, 
82, 76, 64, 80, 63, 78, 59, 73, 69, 68, 52, 76, 61, 62, 58, 69, 
78, 86, 82, 70, 70, 75, 78, 72, 67, 54, 74, 82, 51, 69, 75, 70, 
78, 73, 77, 64, 72, 82, 46, 65, 70, 68, 81, 67, 81, 76, 49, 60, 
70, 68, 66, 75, 74, 70, 62, 62, 72, 43, 68, 55, 74, 65, 82, 77, 
78, 61, 76, 66, 66, 75, 67, 60, 68, 72, 76, 69, 82, 69, 67, 80, 
55, 79, 76, 76, 67, 66, 66, 81, 68, 75, 75, 71, 70, 57, 75, 74, 
64, 71, 66, 68, 66, 92, 76, 64, 76, 55, 63, 57, 70, 79, 71, 77, 
69, 62, 57, 67, 65, 56, 74, 76, 58, 78, 71, 52, 65, 75, 79, 57, 
70, 66, 70, 72, 63, 64, 54, 46, 79, 63, 70, 83, 75, 57, 70, 75, 
69, 65, 81, 46, 68, 65, 65, 63, 74, 75, 81, 64, 82, 61, 65, 69, 
69, 83, 68, 72, 74, 79, 69, 83, 82, 85, 62, 73, 63, 75, 81, 62, 
68, 85, 66, 78, 78, 68, 75, 78, 81, 68, 69, 68, 52, 83, 82, 57, 
77, 55, 83, 74, 74, 64, 74, 58, 47, 74, 72, 71, 56, 66, 84, 67, 
59, 69, 46, 58, 71, 76, 50, 56), smoking = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1), hospit_HF = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), symptomatic_angina = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), cardiac2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), nb_seg_LGE = c(3, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 6, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 
2, 4, 6, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 
2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 6, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 
1, 1, 6, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 
4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 6, 7, 
3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 1, 7, 5, 4, 2, 2, 
5, 5, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 
4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
3, 2, 6, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 5, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 7, 3, 2, 3, 7, 3, 4, 4, 7, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 3, 7, 3, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1), ischemie = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-700L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```